# Identification of a plant (in a pot)

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

I have in my flat a plant which sometime make strange flowers. When the start it looks like plastic stars:

[image: Before Maturity]

Then the flowers are opening after few days and looks like this:

[image: Opened]

The smell is a bit strange (I cannot say bad but definitively not good as other flowers). In general this plant does not need many watering and even I am in Switzerland, I guess it is living normally somewhere else.

For the size, mine is quite small (30 cm high but many wires) but my mother have a very long one along the wall (few meters).

Many picture with higher resolution are in my [flikr gallery](https://www.flickr.com/photos/44724926@N03/sets/72157652252868365).

Anybody can tell me what is the name of this plant and where it lives normally?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya

Comment: flowers looks like Asclepiadaceae

Comment: you could add image of its shoot and leaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [Hoya Carnosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoya_carnosa) [Krinkle Kurl flower](http://www.plantsrescue.com/tag/hoya-carnosa-krinkle-kurl/). It is native to Australia and East Asia. Hoya Carnosa links to wikipedia and Krinkle Kurl links to plant rescue in case you want to read more on it.

[image: http://livingsoganofla.blogspot.com/2011/01/hoya-carnosa-krinkle-curl.html]

[image: http://www.plantsrescue.com/tag/hoya-carnosa-krinkle-kurl/]